# How to debug binding an XDocument to a WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listview, linq-to-xml

I think I'm missing something fundamental in WPF data binding here:

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<WindowList>
  <Window Height="10" Width="10" ALL_MODEL_MODEL="xyz0" ALL_MODEL_MANUFACTURER="leidi"/>
  <Window Height="20" Width="20" ALL_MODEL_MODEL="xyz1" ALL_MODEL_MANUFACTURER="goffin"/>
  <Window Height="30" Width="30" ALL_MODEL_MODEL="xyz2" ALL_MODEL_MANUFACTURER="schlueter"/>
  <Window Height="40" Width="40" ALL_MODEL_MODEL="xyz3" ALL_MODEL_MANUFACTURER="rossi"/>
</WindowList>
```

And this XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="BindListToXDocument.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView Name="lstWindows">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Height" 
                     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Attribute[Height].Value}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Width" 
                     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Attribute[Width].Value}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Model" 
                     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Attribute[Model].Value}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Manufacturer" 
                     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Attribute[Manufacturer].Value}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Populate List</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The binding expressions are modeled after this Document on msdn: [How to: Bind to XDocument, XElement, or LINQ for XML Query Results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165615.aspx).

I then use the following code to set the `DataContext`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load("WindowList.xml");
    var windows = doc.Root.Elements();
    lstWindows.DataContext = windows;
}
```

The code runs without any complaints, when I click the button, but the list items never show up. I can't figure out how to go about debugging this. Do you have any pointers for debugging binding expressions in general or how to bind the `XDocument` specifically?

**EDIT:** OK, it seems I was missing something crucial in my XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lstWindows" ItemsSource="{Binding}"> <!-- specify the ItemsSource! -->
```

I'll leave this question here, since it is a minimal example of binding to an `XDocument`, something I was having trouble finding - most examples already went a step further. I'm still interested in tips for debugging, though.

Comment: Use `output window` to look for possible binding errors

Comment: @Haris Hasan: Good point. The `output window` doesn't mention any binding errors, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did these changes to populate the view...

XAML: set the itemssource property of ListView

```
<ListView Name="lstWindows" Height="400" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}">
```

.CS file : create a property which returns IEnumerable

```
public IEnumerable<XElement> Elements
{
    get
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load(@"\abc.xml");
            var windows = doc.Root.Elements();
            return windows;
        }
}
```

in load method of window... or you can also do this in button click event

`this.DataContext = this;` or `lstWindows.DataContext = this;`

Comment: Thank you. Do you think the `Path=Elements` is necessary here? I think it might be overkill...

Comment: `Path = ` is not necessary you can just say `Binding Elements`, it will work.